# Area of a line - $\infty$ or $0$

Tags: area, infinity

So today read something about two and three dimensional co-ordinate system and also about infinity and something came to me that I have been since pondering on.

So my question is, what is the area of an infinite line? Is it $\infty$ or is it$0$??.

Well if we consider the fact that it is one-dimentional, then of course area is $0$. But since we are mentioning it to be an infinite line, then area should be $\infty$, as it can be making a circle of infinite radius. Can anyone give me a technical explanation for this hypothetical question. Thanks, cheers!!

Comment: It depends on how you define "area"!

Comment: Surely you mean an *ellipse* of infinite radius (major axis)? (i.e. a circle stretched out and flattened into an infinite line). If you just mean it could be a big circle, you are confusing the area of the line with the area enclosed.

Comment: If you think of the line as the circumference of an infinite circle, and you want to know the area "inside" the circle, that region is the entire half-plane on one side of the line and is infinite. But the area of the _circumference_ of a finite circle is zero, just like the area of a finite line segment, so there is no particular reason to think the _circumference_ will have infinite area when the radius becomes infinite.

Comment: @David K, I do really like your answer but actually, my question was whatever area the line encloses in whatever dimension not the area of the line itself in literal. Thanks.

Comment: Area should probably be something like $\int_{line} dA$, which I think is the unambiguous answer to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the limiting process. Say you have a rectangle with length $x$ and width $1/x.$ You take $x\to \infty$ and this starts to look more and more like an infinite line since the length gets infinitely long and the width goes to zero. However, at all times the area is $1,$ which is neither zero, nor infinity.

On the other hand, you could take length $x^2$ and width $1/x$ and then the area would go to to infinity. Or you could take length $x$ and width $1/x^2$ and the area would go to zero. You could also take length $ax$ and width $1/x$ and make the area limit to $a$ for any $a>0.$